# XSL Generate Dynamic and Columns in Pdf template for Apache FOP

Tags: java, xml, xslt, pdf

I am new to style sheets and struggling to create dynamic column in pdf template.. Based on the resultset from java i have to create dynamic column in xsl . The fact is ,I can't able to predict how many columns ,so based on the resultset i have to generate columns dynamically?

down below my xsl code

```
<fo:flow flow-name="mainbody"> 
<fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" padding-top="-13pt">
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" padding-top="105pt">                                    
<fo:table-body height="80cm">
 <xsl:for-each select="t013detailList">
            <fo:table-row  font-size="9pt">
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" text-align="center"  border-bottom="solid 0.01mm gray"   number-columns-spanned="1" wrap-option="wrap">
                             <fo:block > 
                            <xsl:value-of select="AccountNumber"/>
                             </fo:block>
                           </fo:table-cell>
                           </fo:table-row>                                          
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                   </fo:block>
                   </fo:flow>
```

pls help..
All support is welcome. Thanks!